# How to check if a date is after today java

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

Im trying to check whether a date entered by the user is after todays date. Here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date enteredDate = sdf.parse(date);
Date currentDate = new Date();
if(enteredDate.after(currentDate)){
```

Date is a variable with the user date in the format "2016/04/26". After doing some debugging i found that enteredDate and currentDate are null. Any ideas why this is?
Thanks

Comment: currentDate can't be null. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: How could it be that after `Date currentDate = new Date()` the variable `currentDate` is `null`? (Hint: It can't be ...)

Comment: On my computer, with date as `"2016/04/26"`, it works fine.

Comment: It is impossible for currentDate to be null in this context.

Comment: Here the code would have thrown NullPointerException if enteredDate variable is null [i.e. enteredDate.after(new Date())].

Comment: for your code, both ``enteredDate`` and ``currentDate`` should not be ``NULL`` for ``"2016/04/26"``

Comment: try using LocalDate , there has been many changes to DateTime api in java 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it's not possible that Date object will have null reference. However if sdf.parse(date) throws an exception which is suppressed then enteredDate could be null.

```
 String date="2016/04/26";
    Date enteredDate=null;
    try
    {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    enteredDate = sdf.parse(date);
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // enteredDate will be null if date="287686";
    }
    Date currentDate = new Date();      
    if(enteredDate.after(currentDate)){
        System.out.println("after ");
    }else
        System.out.println("before");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "2016/04/26";
        Date enteredDate = null;
        Date matcher = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        try {
            enteredDate = sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();// enteredDate will be null if date="287686";
        }

        try {
            matcher = sdf.parse("2016/04/26");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (enteredDate.compareTo(matcher) == 0) {
            System.out.println("enteredDate will be null");
        }

        Date currentDate = new Date();
        if (enteredDate.after(currentDate)) {
            System.out.println("after ");
        } else
            System.out.println("before");
    }
}
```